# Error con scope

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código, y un error muy común que tengo es que nosé mucho controlar el `scope` entre `HTML` y `Javascript`, con eso me refiero a que muchas veces cuando llamo una función directamente desde el HTML y esa función está en un archivo **js** aparte, siempre me dice que la función **no esta definida**, como aquí:

Como pueden ver al cliquear los inputs de texto, en consola sale que la función no está definida.

La función que dice no estar definida es la `checkRealTime`, esa función se la agrego por `onblur` a todos los `inputs` del documento(creo porque además el `onblur` no funciona correctamente al *primer click*, entonces deben haber mas errores aún...)

¿Cómo arreglar esto , y porqué sucede?

```js
/* Independent functions */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',functions); /* Waiting for DOM Load */

function functions(){
var getLabels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'),j=0,lmax=getLabels.length;
for(;j<lmax;j++) { getLabels[j].style.fontFamily = 'Monospace'; }
validateInputs();
function checkRealTime(id){
 console.log(id);
}
}

function validateInputs(){
 var pattern = /[0-9]/;
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
 for(let i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
  inputs[i].setAttribute('onblur','checkRealTime('+inputs[i].id+')');
 }
 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zero to hero ?</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
<script src="igenerator.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- I define the default css values !-->
<style>
body { color: gray; margin: 0;}
.title { font-family: monospace; color: black; font-size: 25px; margin-left: 35vw;} 
.ms { font-family: monospace;}
</style>
<body>
  <b class="title">Javascript Input generator(and can be deleted)</b>
  <hr></hr>
   <label for="inputgen"> Number of inputs to be generated: </label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="to add" id='inputgen'> <input type="button" value="Generate" id='b-generate'>

   <label for="idel"> Number of inputs to be deleted: </label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="to delete" id="idel"> <input type="button" value="Delete" id="b-delete">
   <hr></hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion `checkRealTime` esta definida dentro del metodo `functions` por lo que solo sera visible para las funciones/eventos que sean declarados dentro de la funcion `functions`, asi que la funcion `validateInputs` nunca podra obtener la referencia de la funcion `checkRealTime` porque esta definida *fuera* de la funcion `functions`:

```js
function functions() {
   //.. 
    // solo esta definida para uso interno de la funcion functions
    function checkRealTime(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
    checkRealTime(1); // valido
}

functions();
setTimeout(checkRealTime, 3000);// invocarla despues de los 3 segundos y fallara diciendo que no esta definida en su ambito
```

Tienes que definir la funcion en el mismo ambito de visibilidad o un ambito mas alto de donde esta siendo invocada. Por ejemplo definiendola fuera de la function `functions` funcionaria:

```js
function functions() {
    //.. 
    // solo esta definida para uso interno de la funcion functions
    checkRealTime(1); // valido
}
function checkRealTime(id) {
    console.log(id);
}

function validateInputs(){
 functions();
   setTimeout(function(){
    checkRealTime(2);
   }, 3000);// invocarla despues de los 3 segundos e imprimira 2
 }
  validateInputs();
```

Aqui funcion para ambos porque estan en el mismo nivel de ambito o alcanse.

Tambien puedes hacer la funcion checkRealTime publica si la declaras con el objeto `window` que en escencia seria lo mismo que declararla fuera del metodo `functions`:

```js
    function functions() {
       //.. 
        // solo esta definida para uso interno de la funcion functions
        window.checkRealTime = function(id) {
            console.log(id);
        }
        checkRealTime(1); // valido
    }

    functions();
    setTimeout(function(){ checkRealTime(3); }, 3000);// invocarla despues de los 3 segundos
```

Por lo que tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
/* Independent functions */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',functions); /* Waiting for DOM Load */

function functions(){
   var getLabels = 
   document.getElementsByTagName('label'),j=0,lmax=getLabels.length;
   for(;j<lmax;j++) { 
     getLabels[j].style.fontFamily = 'Monospace';
   }
   validateInputs();
}

function checkRealTime(id){
    console.log(id);
}

function validateInputs(){
    var pattern = /[0-9]/;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for(let i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
        inputs[i].setAttribute('onblur','checkRealTime('+inputs[i].id+')');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en donde has definido checkRealTime, ya que está la has creado dentro de otra función. Además, cuando creas de forma dinámica la llamada a la función checkRealTime, el programa te tomará los parámetros como nombres de variables, no como variables. A mi me funciona dejándolo así:

```
/* Independent functions */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',functions); /* Waiting for DOM Load */

function functions(){

var getLabels = document.getElementsByTagName('label'),j=0,lmax=getLabels.length;
for(;j<lmax;j++) { getLabels[j].style.fontFamily = 'Monospace'; }
validateInputs();

}
function checkRealTime(id){
    console.log(id);
}
function validateInputs(){

    var pattern = /[0-9]/;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for(let i = 0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
        console.log(i)
        inputs[i].setAttribute('onblur','checkRealTime("'+inputs[i].id+'")');
    }
}
```